# Game stat calculations

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, model

I am creating some kind of php/js browser game like Ogame or something similar. The game is based on clicking and waiting basicly. User has his points per level that he can add to stranght, agility, stamina etc.

Now my question is: Let's say that 1 point of stamina gives 3 points of life to particular hero, and 5 to another one. Where should I keep such a calculations?
The points are already being stored in database. I will need to use them a lot. For example Agility gives you Armor, Magic resistance, speed. It will be needed in fight calculations and to be displayed at the main screen of the game. But every of possible heros have some different calculations

I am using Laravel 4.2, should it be stored in models maybe? To be honest this is my first project and I am not very advanced in these things. Could somebody advice me please?

Comment: in database.. but your question is too broad

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RiggsFolly "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" - doesn't my question match this point? I am asking where should i count these numbers. Maybe i should create some class with static information about each hero or create a table that contains some numbers that i will multiple by the number of stats?

Comment: Your question might be ok from the perspective you quoted in your comment, but at the same time it's very broad. The fact that you give descriptions such as _"some kind of php/js browser game"_ or _"But every of possible heros have some different calculations"_ means that we have to make assumptions about logic and how your game will work and that makes the question broad. I can tell your that at first glance it makes sense not to keep all that logic in the models as you inquired, but that's about it.

Comment: As a side note, if this is by chance a new Laravel project (and from your question it would seem so), you should really **not be using** an old version of Laravel. Support will be dropped at some point for bugfixes, if it has not been dropped already. So I would suggest you use Laravel 5.1.